# Unwanted bigskip/double line spacing/gap for itemize in Beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize, line-spacing

This is unwanted blank space i would like to remove it, here is my MWE:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[secheader]{Madrid}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setmainlanguage{english}   
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}       
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%
%\newcommand{\ar}{\textarabic}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{itemize}
\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
\begin{Arabic}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}         
\item نص عربي
\begin{itemize}
\item نص عربي
\end{itemize}
\item نص عربي               
\end{itemize}
\begin{block}{}
\begin{itemize}             
\item نص عربي
\begin{itemize}             
\item نص عربي
\item نص عربي
\end{itemize}
\item نص عربي
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{exampleblock}{}
\begin{itemize}             
\item نص عربي
\begin{itemize}
\item نص عربي
\item نص عربي
\end{itemize}
\item نص عربي
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{columns}
\end{Arabic}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: blank space]

Comment: Can you make a MWE that does not rely on special fonts? More people will be able to help you then.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, i updated the MWE with a common font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where this additional space comes from, but a quick hack to remove it:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[secheader]{Madrid}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}   
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}       
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%

\AtBeginEnvironment{Arabic}{%
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody end}{\vspace{-0.6cm}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{Arabic}
\begin{itemize}         
\item test
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\item test
\end{itemize}
\item test       
\end{itemize}
test
\end{Arabic}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}         
\item test
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}
\item test       
\end{itemize}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

*(you may need to finetune the value of `-0.6cm`)*

Comment: @AbdelhakElfengour You're welcome!